How to review Azure Devops git repo pull request in an IDE like Visual Studio?
I wonder if there is a way to review pull requests in an IDE like environment (which is easier to visualise merge conflicts). The main pain point is having to check merge conflicts resulting from the pull requests in the browser.
I have explored Azure website tutorials and there is some info on how to deal with the repos in Visual Studio. But they always seem to suggest using the browser for reviewing pull requests/ checking merge conflicts in the pull requests.
Any idea on how to use Visual Studio / any other IDE for this task?

Yes, there is an extension for VS Code that does just that. You can see it here and install it: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ankitbko.vscode-pull-request-azdo
These are the features listed:

Authenticating and connecting VS Code to Azure Devops.
Listing and browsing PRs from within VS Code.
Reviewing PRs from within VS Code with in-editor commenting.
Validating PRs from within VS Code with easy checkouts.
Suggest edits to the PR Author. Author can apply edits directly from Description page.
Mark file as viewed when reviewing PR.

